# python 3, comparing elements of two lists of lists

Tags: list, python-3.8

I'm trying to compare elements of 2 lists of lists in python. I want to create a new list (ph) which has a 1 if elements of lists from the 1st list of lists are in the elements of the 2nd list of lists.
However, this seems to compare the whole list and not individual elements. The code is below. Many thanks for the help! :)

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

abc = [[1,800000,3],[4,5,6],[100000,7,8]]
l = [[
   [i for i in range(0, 100000)],
   [i for i in range(200000,300000)],
   [i for i in range(400000,500000)],
   [i for i in range(600000,700000)],
   [i for i in range(800000,900000)],
   [i for i in range(1000000,1100000)]
]]
ph = []
for i in abc:
    for j in l:
        if l[0] == abc[0]:
           ph.append(1)
        else:
           ph.append(0)
print(ph)
```

Answer (score 0):

The goal of your problem is somewhat unclear to me. Correct me if I'm wrong but what you want is: for each sublist of abc, get a boolean describing if all its elements are anywhere in l. Is that it ?
If it is indeed the case, here's my answer.
First of all, your second list is not a list of lists but a list of lists of lists. Hence, I removed a nested list in my code.

```py
abc = [[1,800000,3],[4,5,6],[100000,7,8]]
L = [
   [i for i in range(0, 100000)],
   [i for i in range(200000,300000)],
   [i for i in range(400000,500000)],
   [i for i in range(600000,700000)],
   [i for i in range(800000,900000)],
   [i for i in range(1000000,1100000)]
]
flattened_L = sum(L, [])
print(
    list(map(lambda sublist: all(x in flattened_L for x in sublist), abc))
)
# returns [True, True, False]
```

My code first flattens `L` so that is becomes easy to check whether any element is in it or not. Then, for each sublist in `abc`, it checks if all elements are in this flattened list.
Note: my code returns a list of boolean. If you absolutely need integers value (0 and 1), which you shouldn't, you can wrap `int` around `all`.